# Vector::iterator crashes on compare with begin

Tags: c++, vector, insert, iterator

I am trying to iterate in reverse through a vector. I've "made" an iterator using a typedef:

```
typedef std::vector<Object*>::iterator Cursor;
```

My problem is, this function seems to crash when it reaches the begin of the vector. I have the following code:

```
void InsertFunc(Cursor& it, Object& o) {
     vec_.insert(it, o);
     --it;
     for (; it >= vec_.begin(); --it) {
         if ((*it)->type() == Object::SomeType) {
             do_something
         } else {
             do_something_else
         }
     }
std::cout << "Insertion succes!" << std::endl;
}
```

I've tested it already, and I know for sure that the function reaches the begin of the vector, but then the program just terminates and the message "Insertion succes!" is never printed. Any idea why?

Comment: Run it through your debugger and obtain more information than "it just terminates". Also, this likely depends on what `do_something` and `do_something_else` do. I suspect an erase mechanic gone wrong. http://sscce.org

Comment: If you are wanting to modify the contents of the container while iterating, `std::deque` is probably what you are after

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know for sure the iterator will never be at vec_.begin() when this function is called.

Comment: If you're inserting at the end of the vector you might be better off with push_back. If you're inserting at the front or back of the vector you might be better off with deque. If you're inserting in the middle of the vector you might be better off with list, but all of those considerations depend on what else you're doing with the vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your iterator is potentially invalidated by the `insert`, if the elements had to be moved in memory due to a growing re-allocation.

You can obtain a new, valid iterator from the insert call itself:

```
it = vec_.insert(it, o);
```

And away you go.

Your following line, `--it`, will cause a failure if the new element was already *at* `begin()`; you've just iterated past the beginning. I'd revisit the logic of this function entirely, to be honest.

---

<sup>- [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6438086/560648)</sup>

Comment: I didn't know that insert could invalidate the iterator. This worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, the call to `vec.insert( it, o )` can invalidate `it`.
You want:

```
it = vec.insert( it, o );
```

(which returns an iterator to the inserted element).

Second, if `it` was equal to `vec.begin()`, the following `--it`
is illegal.

And third, if `it >= vec.begin()` can never be false, unless the
code contains undefined behavior: the valid range of iterators
is `it >= vec.begin() && it < vec.end()`.  (But we usually try
to avoid comparisons for inequality on iterators, because not
all iterators support them.

What you probably want is something like:

```
void InsertFunc( Cursor& it, Object const& o )
{
    it = vec.insert( it, o );
    while ( it != vec.begin() ) {
        -- it;
        //  ...
    }
}
```

When iterating backwards over a range, the usual solution is to
use a `while`, with the decrementation at the top.

Alternatively, you can use reverse iterators:

```
void InsertFunc( Cursor& it, Object const& o )
{
    typedef std::vector<Object>::reverse_iterator RCursor;
    it = vec.insert( it, o );
    for (RCursor rit = RCursor(it); rit != vec.rend(); ++ rit ) {
        //  ...
    }
}
```

(Regretfully, there doesn't seem to be a `make_reverse`
function.  It wouldn't be hard to write, however.)

Comment: What would `make_reverse` do, that the existing `RCursor` constructor does not already do?

Comment: Implicit type deduction.  With `make_reverse` and `auto`, you wouldn't need the typedef, and you'd never have to spell out the type.  (Same reason we have `make_pair`, for example.)

Comment: Ah, yes. That'll do. However I'd quite like _not_ to see C++ introduce `make_*` for all `*` just to satisfy the `auto`-mongers!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree in general.  Between `make_...` and `auto`, it's possible to write a program without having the slightest idea what types are involved.  But iterators do seem to be a special case.  They're used in very limited contexts, in very special ways, which tends to make the type more or less clear, or at least clear enough for someone reading the code to understand what is going on.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And just to be clear: even with iterators, the use of `make_...` and `auto` is really only tolerable for loops like the above.  The `make_...` are also useful when calling a template function.

Comment: I guess I have a problem with the emerging pattern of making a `make_*` for things, as if this were PHP. It seems so... analogue. But then without (gasp!) specifying a type, this is what we're left with: half the name of a function arbitrarily specifying a kind of type "category". Yuck!